# Laravel Api Deployed in apache2 Ubuntu Routing Problem

Tags: php, laravel, api, routes

Hello i have set a laravel project to build an api, i used the passport mechanism to create the authorization.

My api works perfect with `php artisan serve` on http://localhost:8000

I call api like http://localhost:8000/api/test

But when i deployed my laravel api project in an apache2 ubuntu server the project i cant call the api service.

The link in the apache seems like http://localhost:8000/laravel_project/public

Does anyone here knows how i call the api from the apache2.

For example i tried http://localhost:8000/laravel_project/public/api/test and it didnt work.

Which is the correct link format to call the api.

Thank you.

Comment: pass route on this link is a good to test api https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: have you set up a vhost? If yes, share it with us

Comment: i test it but it doesnt work even with postman.

Comment: Even if i setup a vhost pointing to public its the same thing nothing changes.